# Why did he use "typedef vector<double>::size_type" instead of using "int"

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, typedef

I am just learning C++ and I am using Accelerated C++.

In a vector example, the writer used the following code;

```
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
vec_sz size = homework.size;
```

I know `typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;` is so that he doesn't have to write the next command as `vector<double>::size_type size = homework.size;`, but my question is why didn't he just declare `size` as an integer instead?

```
int size = homework.size;
```

Is this because we are using a vector?

If so, does that mean that the values returned by vector iterators cannot be stored in regular variables?

Comment: Here's a question for you: what's the type behind `vector<double>::size_type`?

Comment: The short answer is that the writer could and probably should have used `size_t`, but that that is *not* the same as `int` (it's *usually* either the same as `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`; the unsignedness of it matters a great deal and the size difference can also matter depending what you're doing).  The long answer is much too long even for the actual answer box; a _good_ C++ book will in fact explain what the deal is with `int` vs `size_t` vs `container<T>::size_type` but it sounds like yours didn't.

Comment: The point is we do not know exactly what type is behind `std::vector<double>::size_type` but whatever type it is we want a short-hand way of declaring it. Its unlikely to be a `int` btw. We do know that it is a type that can hold numbers large enough to address the maximum number of elements in a *vector*.

Comment: "*but my question is why didn't he just declare size as an integer instead?*" -- **He did.** Both `int` and `vector<double>::size_type` are integer types. Don't confuse "integer" (a collection of types) with `int` (one specific type within that collection).

Comment: @zwol What benefit does using size_type have over using size_t?

Comment: @Galik `vector<T>::size_type` is defined as `size_t` by the standard. It's only necessary to use `size_type` if you have used a non-standard allocator

Comment: @M.M Interesting. In my copy of the standard it says that vector::size_type is *implementation defined* but it is unsigned integral type capable of representing any non-negative value of `difference_type`.

Comment: @Galik, M.M: C++98 and C++11/N3337 specify that `std::allocator<T>::size_type` is  `size_t`. However, they explicitly _don't_ require `container<T, Alloc<T> >::size_type` to be the same as `Alloc<T>::size_type`, which I think is _probably_ a mistake but I am not sure I understand all of the implications myself.   It sounds like `vector<int>::size_type` might be unrelated to `size_t`, but as a QoI matter it damn well ought to be `size_t`.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, found your question to be usefull. Thanks mate! I think we are reading the same book (;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why didn't he just declare size as an integer?

Because integer is not the correct type to store vector's size, for two reasons:

- `int` is allowed to be negative; size of a vector is non-negative
- Even an unsigned `int` may not be large enough to hold maximal vector size

`int` would work fine for small vectors, but for a general approach you should use `vector<T>::size_type`. Note that the type is unsigned, so you need to be careful when iterating by index back to front.

> does that mean that the values returned by vector iterators cannot be stored in regular variables?

Iterators are not of type `vector<T>::size_type`, it is separate data type altogether.

Comment: So in essence we are using size_type because it will be able to hold a larger size that an unsigned int will? If I am reading your reply correctly.

Comment: @OlaniyiJinadu Yes, that's essentially the thing. If you use vector's typedef, you don't have to worry about if the index is going to fit or not.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, [`std::vector::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is not `int`.

> Unsigned integral type (usually [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t))

And

> `std::size_t` is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator as well as the `sizeof...` operator and the `alignof` operator (since C++11).

Secondly, from c++11 you can use [`auto specifier`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) to deduce the type automatically.

```
auto size = homework.size();
```

BTW: `homework.size` seems weird, you might mean `homework.size()`.